# Retrieve data from collection in sorted order of field "Date_Created" which is of type string

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-.net-driver

**Model:**

```
public class WorkSheetModel
{
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Date_Created { get; set; }
}
```

**Collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5510323a50ef4e04a0404815"),
    "Name" : "Example",
    "Date_Created" : "Sunday, 19 March 2015 01:10 PM"
}
```

**Retrieving Data:**

```
public WorkSheetModel getWorkSheets(WorkSheetModel oModel)
{
  var worksheet = _db.GetCollection<WorkSheetModel>("WorkSheet");
  oModel.SortBy="Date_Created";

  workSheetCursor = worksheet.Find(_query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending(oModel.SortBy)).SetLimit(oModel.ItemsPerPage).SetSkip(oModel.ItemsPerPage * (oModel.PageNo - 1));

  oModel.WorkSheetList = new List<WorkSheetModel>();
  foreach (WorkSheetModel _worksheet in workSheetCursor)
  {
      oModel.WorkSheetList.Add(_worksheet);
  }

}
```

In my collection the **"Date_Created"** field is of type **"String"** which holds date. Now I want to retrieve data from this collection sorted in ascending order of "Date_Created", but as "Date_Created" field is of type string, the data retrieved in alphabetically arranged order of "Date_Created".

Is it possible to retrieve data in sorted order of field **"Date_Created"** without changing the field data type?

Comment: No, it isn't. Save it as an ISODate, which has the additional advantage of being more precise in terms of timezones. Then you can sort by date. In order to display the date, I am sure there is a possibility to display it in a proper format by providing (milli-)seconds since epoch.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - Yah! I also think this is the only option left for me. Thanks.